# Copying an array in CUDA

Tags: pointers, memory, cuda

Why doesn't my `cudaMemcpy` work? I wrapped it in `checkCUDAErrors`, a debugging function provided by the class I'm taking. My program has no errors except for one:

```
CUDA error at: student_func.cu:202
invalid argument cudaMemcpy(&d_filter,&h_filter, sizeof(float) * filterWidth * 
filterWidth, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

NVCC did not report any error, however. Where am I going wrong?

```
unsigned char *d_red, *d_green, *d_blue;
const float* const *d_filter;

void allocateMemoryAndCopyToGPU(const size_t numRowsImage, const size_t numColsImage,
                                const float* const h_filter, const size_t filterWidth)
{

  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_red,   sizeof(unsigned char) * numRowsImage * numColsImage));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_green, sizeof(unsigned char) * numRowsImage * numColsImage));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_blue,  sizeof(unsigned char) * numRowsImage * numColsImage));
  d_filter = &h_filter;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_filter, sizeof(float) * filterWidth * filterWidth));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&d_filter,&h_filter, sizeof(float) * filterWidth * filterWidth, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); //line with error

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype is :

```
cudaMemcpy  (   void *  dst,
const void *    src,
size_t  count,
enum cudaMemcpyKind     kind     
)
```

So you should get rid of the & and not make dst as const

So change this:

```
const float* const *d_filter;
```

to this:

```
float *d_filter;
```

And change this:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&d_filter,&h_filter, sizeof(float) * filterWidth * filterWidth, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); //line with error
```

to this:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_filter,h_filter, sizeof(float) * filterWidth * filterWidth, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Comment: Both i think. Those already are pointers, using & pass pointer to pointer

Comment: that causes NVCC to give the following error: `student_func.cu(203): error: argument of type "const float *const *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"`

Comment: Yes, remove the const

Comment: In your float declaration

Comment: I changed it to `const float* *d_filter;` and got the following error: student_func.cu(188): error: a value of type "const float *const *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "const float **"

Comment: That error refers to the line `d_filter = &h_filter;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65020/discussion-between-rene-g-and-eric).

Comment: You also don't need the & for that line